# R Paste All Variables With Specific Prefix

Tags: r

I would like to paste the content of a set of variables with a given prefix. For example, given this data:

```
data <- data.frame(var_1=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   var_2=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   var_3=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

I want to replicate the following behavior without listing each variable name individually, instead pasting all variables with the prefix "var_":

```
my_strings <- paste(toy_data$var_1,
                    toy_data$var_2,
                    toy_data$var_3)

my_strings
[1] "1 1 1" "2 2 2" "3 3 3" "4 4 4" "5 5 5"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `do.call` for row wise paste

```
do.call(paste, data[startsWith(names(data), 'var')])
#[1] "1 1 1" "2 2 2" "3 3 3" "4 4 4" "5 5 5"
```

Or instead of `startsWith`, use `grep`

```
do.call(paste, data[grep("^var_\\d+$", names(data))])
```

Or with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(paste, data[startsWith(names(data), 'var')])
#[1] "1 1 1" "2 2 2" "3 3 3" "4 4 4" "5 5 5"
```

Another option is `apply`, but it would be slow

```
apply(data[startsWith(names(data), 'var')], 1, paste, collapse= ' ')
#[1] "1 1 1" "2 2 2" "3 3 3" "4 4 4" "5 5 5"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `purrr` and `dplyr`, you can do:

```
reduce(select(data, starts_with("var")), paste)

[1] "1 1 1" "2 2 2" "3 3 3" "4 4 4" "5 5 5"
```